# How to have 2 differents settings in Scrapy?

Tags: scrapy

I want to change some parametres for one of my spiders in settings.
I read the [doc official](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html) of Scrapy 
i tried this:

```
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'mySpider'
    custom_settings = {
        DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
            'Crawling.middlewares.ProxyMiddleware' : 100,
                'Crawling.middlewares.RandomUserAgentMiddleware' : 400,
                'scrapy.dowloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware' : None,
                'scrapyjs.SplashMiddleware' : 725,
        },
            COOKIES_ENABLED= True,
            DOWNLOAD_DELAY= 0,
    }
```

but i got this error

```
    DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Try it like this: `'DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES' :`

Comment: @RafaelAlmeida Thanks rafael, it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting name must be a dict key, take a look at the [doc](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#settings-per-spider)

```
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'mySpider'
    custom_settings = {
        'DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES': {
            'Crawling.middlewares.ProxyMiddleware' : 100,
                'Crawling.middlewares.RandomUserAgentMiddleware' : 400,
                'scrapy.dowloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware' : None,
                'scrapyjs.SplashMiddleware' : 725,
        },
        'COOKIES_ENABLED': True,
        'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 0,
    }
```